# Git Extensions using Putty: The Servers Host Key is Not Cached in the Registry (but I think it is)

Tags: ssh, git, putty, gerrit

Following the commands below, I am under the impression that my key is added to "the registry". What am I doing, or where is putty screwing up. I should note that scp alone works because I coppied my id_rsa key from my cygwin installation to my /c/Users/mehoggan/.ssh diroctory and ssh-add'd it. However it is the git portion that is not working. My .ppk file is located in PuTTY's default location /c/Users/mehoggan/Documents. The public version was coppied and pasted up to gerrit.

```
$ /c/Program\ Files/GitExtensions/PuTTY/plink.exe -P 29418 -l mehoggan matthewh.me
The server's host key is not cached in the registry. You
have no guarantee that the server is the computer you
think it is.
The server's rsa2 key fingerprint is:
"finger print"
If you trust this host, enter "y" to add the key to
PuTTY's cache and carry on connecting.
If you want to carry on connecting just once, without
adding the key to the cache, enter "n".
If you do not trust this host, press Return to abandon the
connection.
Store key in cache? (y/n) y
Using username "mehoggan".

  ****    Welcome to Gerrit Code Review    ****

  Hi Matthew Hoggan, you have successfully connected over SSH.

  Unfortunately, interactive shells are disabled.
  To clone a hosted Git repository, use:

  git clone ssh://mehoggan@www.matthewh.me:29418/REPOSITORY_NAME.git


mehoggan@MEHOGGAN-PC ~/Devel
$ git clone ssh://mehoggan@www.matthewh.me:29418/gerrit-userstats && scp -p -P 29418 mehoggan@www
.matthewh.me:hooks/commit-msg gerrit-userstats/.git/hooks/
Cloning into 'gerrit-userstats'...
The server's host key is not cached in the registry. You
have no guarantee that the server is the computer you
think it is.
The server's rsa2 key fingerprint is:
<finger print>
Connection abandoned.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first part, you are connecting to `matthewh.me`, and in the second one you are connectiong to `www.matthewh.met`.

The first connection stored the host key for `matthewh.me`.

The second connection asks for the host key, because the key for `www.matthewh.me` isn't yet stored.

You should connect with putty to `www.matthewh.me`, and store the host key before running git.